# Encoding non-mandatory feature properties in WFS/GML?

Tags: wfs, gml

In what ways can non-mandatory feature properties be encoded in feature type schema (WFS 2.0/GML 3.2.1 with GML features)?

Comment: Non-mandatory property is not mandatory. You can select which attributes you want to get with `PROPERTYNAME=` but you can't skip mandatory attributes. Non-mandatory ones have `minOccurs="0" nillable="true"` in the schema.

Comment: @user30184 , Should such property appear in server response by default (without `propertynames` parameter)? As for feature schema, are the `minOccurs=0` and `nillable` the only ways to define property as not mandatory?

Comment: Why not to read the standards first? In http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/04-094r1/04-094r1.html you can read `If no <wfs:PropertyName>elements or <wfs:XlinkPropertyName> elements are specified, then all feature properties should be fetched.`.

Comment: @user30184 , I apologize, I forgot to specify that I am interested in standard v2.0. There is no XLinkPropertyName in WFS 2.0 schema

Comment: There seems to be `KVP-encoding of projection clause` in WFS 2.0 standard and it is using PROPERTYNAME.

Comment: Yes, i'm about projection clause. The standard specification says: Every feature representation generated by a WFS **shall** include all the mandatory properties for the feature type according to the schema description, and then **may** include a selection of the other properties, according to the schema description. Considering **may**, in theory, I can include the optional properties in the answer by default and it will not be a non-compliant, but I'm not sure

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.